# How to store the CLOB data into Oracle table in XML format

Tags: xml-parsing

I tried to load the XML data into Oracle table. Here first we are loading the data into one oracle table with CLOB datatype. Then we tried to split that XML tags and tried to store into another table based on the XMLS columns. How to achieve this?

- Table 1: column with CLOB datatype and stored the entire XML data
- Table 2: Create columns based on the xml with XMLTYPE datatypes and loading that data from table1 into table2.

Note: In this step 2, I'm not loading only attribute value. I'm loading based on the XML TAGS. Because in my XML we have more TAGS and Sub TAGS.

Existing code having this

```
,(select column_value from table (xmlsequence (extract(
   (select xml_text from stab tin where tin.src_name =tout.src_name) ,
 '/XX/YY')))) YY
```